# Why does q/\\a/ equal q/\a/?

Tags: perl, backslash, single-quotes

The following example prints "SAME":

```
if (q/\\a/ eq q/\a/) {
    print "SAME\n";
}
else {
    print "DIFFERENT\n";
}
```

I understand this is consistent with the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators). But I think this behavior is undesirable. Is there a need to escape a backlash **lilteral** in single-quoted string? If I wanted 2 backlashes, I'd need to specify 4; this does not seem convenient.

Shouldn't Perl detect whether a backslash serves as an escape character or not? For instance, when a backslash does not precede a delimiter, it should be treated as a literal; and if that were the case, I wouldn't need 3 backslashes to express two, e.g.,

```
q<a\\b>
```

instead of

```
q<a\\\b>.
```

Comment: Try using `q/\/` and you'll see the need to escape backslashes.

Comment: Sorry, I was not completely clear in my original question. I've added the word "literal" to emphasize the fact when the backslash does not function as an escape character. Your example does not reflect my point in question as in your case, according to definition, the backslash preceding a delimiter acts as an escape char.

Comment: "when a backslash does not precede a delimiter, it should be treated as a literal" Then how do you create a string that ends in a backslash? `q/\/` -> literal slash, no closing delimiter (syntax error); `q/\\/` -> literal backslash, literal slash, no closing delimiter (syntax error); `q/\\\/` -> literal backslash, literal backslash, literal slash, no closing delimiter (syntax error); ...

Comment: "...how do you create a string that ends in a backslash?" --- An excellent use case! Since it _does_ precede the (closing) delimiter, it should not be treated as a literal and thus needs to be escaped. Aside from this use case, I think my suggestion would work when a backlash appears anywhere inside and not next a closing delimiter.

Comment: @Ltf4an Yes, but how do you know you've reached the closing delimiter? `q/\\/` could be a single (escaped) backslash, or it could be just the beginning of the string `\/`, with more to follow to the right. Which one does the parser choose? What you've described is ambiguous.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, how about walking backward from the closing delimiter? I'd think the 1st char preceding the closing delimiter must not be a backlash. If it is, it's an error; if it's not but it's another closing delimiter, then the next preceding char must be a backlash, etc.

Comment: You can't walk backward from the closing delimiter unless you know where the closing delimiter is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is there a need to escape a backlash in single-quoted string?

Yes, if the backslash is followed by another backslash, or is the last character in the string:

```
$ perl -e'print q/C:\/'
Can't find string terminator "/" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
$ perl -e'print q/C:\\/'
C:\
```

This makes it possible to include any character in a single-quoted string, including the delimiter and the escape character.

---

> If I wanted 2 backlashes, I'd need to specify 4; this does not seem convenient.

Actually, you only need three (because the second backslash isn't followed by another backslash). But as an alternative, if your string contains a lot of backslashes you can use a single-quoted heredoc, which requires no escaping:

```
my $path = <<'END';
C:\a\very\long\path
END

chomp $path;
print $path; # C:\a\very\long\path
```

Note that the heredoc adds a newline to the end, which you can remove with `chomp`.

Comment: *"you can use a single-quoted heredoc, which requires no escaping"* Thank you for that. I have always believed that a *heredoc* with a single-quoted terminator behaved exactly the same as a single-quoted string, except that there is no "delimiter" to escape, so only multiple backslashes must be escaped. I am very pleased to be wrong.

Comment: I've edited my question to make the case that Perl should distinguish between literal backslash and escaping backslash.

Answer (score 10):

In single-quoted string literals,

> A backslash represents a backslash unless followed by the delimiter or another backslash, in which case the delimiter or backslash is interpolated.

In other words,

- You must escape delimiters.
- You must escape `\` that are followed by `\` or the delimiter.
- You may escape `\` that aren't followed by `\` or the delimiter.

So,

```
q/\//      ⇒   /
q/\\\\a/   ⇒   \\a
q/\\\a/    ⇒   \\a
q/\\a/     ⇒   \a
q/\a/      ⇒   \a
```

---

> *Is there a need to escape a backlash in single-quoted string?*

Yes, if it's followed by another backslash or the delimiter.

> *If I wanted 2 backlashes, I'd need to specify 4*

Three would suffice.

> *this does not seem convenient.*

It's more convenient than double-quoted strings, where backslashes must always be escaped. Single-quoted string require the minimum amount of escaping possible without losing the ability to produce the delimiter.